# Merging two gensim Phrases models

Tags: python, gensim

I am trying to build a Phrases model over a big corpus but I keep stumbling over a memory error. 
First I tried to fit my entire corpus into a big generator.
Then, I tried to save the model between each document :

```
import codecs
import gensim
import os
import random
import string
import sys

def gencorp(file_path):
    with codecs.open(file_path, 'rb',encoding="utf8") as doc :
        for sentence in doc:
            yield sentence.split()

out_corpus_dir = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/word2vec/1billionwords_corpus_preprocessed/"
file_nb = 0
bi_detector = gensim.models.Phrases()
for file in os.listdir(out_corpus_dir):
    file_nb += 1
    file_path = out_corpus_dir+file
    bi_detector.add_vocab(gencorp(file_path))
    bi_detector.save("generic_EN_bigrams_v%i"%(file_nb/10))
    bi_detector = gensim.models.Phrases.load("generic_EN_bigrams_v%i"%(file_nb/10))
bi_detector.save("generic_EN_bigrams")
```

But none of these solutions work. However, generic_EN_bigrams_v0 is generated and saved.
So I am wondering if I can train a Phrases model per document and then find a way to merge them after.

Thanks you for any insight :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the `gensim`'s documentation, adding sentences should simply work, and you shouldn't have a memory problem since it's updating the statistics only. Therefore, this minor modification to your code should make it work, i.e. you don't need to recreate the `bi_detector` object.

```
import codecs
import gensim
import os
import random
import string
import sys

def gencorp(file_path):
    with codecs.open(file_path, 'rb',encoding="utf8") as doc :
        for sentence in doc:
            yield sentence.split()

out_corpus_dir = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/word2vec/1billionwords_corpus_preprocessed/"
file_nb = 0
bi_detector = gensim.models.Phrases()
for file in os.listdir(out_corpus_dir):
    file_nb += 1
    file_path = out_corpus_dir+file
    bi_detector.add_vocab(gencorp(file_path))
    # The following two lines are not required.
    # bi_detector.save("generic_EN_bigrams_v%i"%(file_nb/10))
    # bi_detector = gensim.models.Phrases.load("generic_EN_bigrams_v%i"%(file_nb/10))
bi_detector.save("generic_EN_bigrams")
```

Comment: any idea how to parallelize this process? Is it possible to create a bi_detector object in each thread (i.e., for each file in directory) and finally combine them?